# how do i make this responsive nav bar work properly?

Tags: css, responsive-design, navigation

i am trying to make a responsive navigation bar with these 4 elements. however, if i drag the browserwindow to a certrain point it starts placing one of the 4 below the rest. but i dont know what i'm doing wrong.

The HTML:

```
<div id="nav">    
   <ul>
       <li class="blue"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li class="blue"><a href="#">Trailer</a></li>
       <li class="red"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
       <li clas="red"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:transparant;
}

#nav ul {
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 24%;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color:#242424;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#nav ul li a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining what you want it to do...

Comment: sorry, i wanted them to be side by side

Comment: ok, but when you get to a point where they can't fit on one line, then what? This is why they will drop down onto multiple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are maybe having problems with your padding.

For that, add the box-sizing property in your lis and the padding will be included in the width of the element, like:

```
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 24%;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color:#242424;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/begyu5v3/

Info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

And there's those undesirable white spaces between your lis. In this [link](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), there are some ways to avoid this problem, like font-size:

```
#nav ul {
    font-size: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Comment: oh my god thank you so much! it works completely as desired now :D

Comment: Very glad that helped! :)